# Sensitivity of Lebesgue measure of level sets

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions, lebesgue-measure

Assume we are given some constant $\alpha$ and a subset $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\lambda(\Omega)<\infty$, where lambda denotes the Lebesgue measure. We consider the mapping
$$
\Lambda:L^1(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}
$$
with
$$
\Lambda(f)=\lambda(\{x\in\Omega: f(x)>\alpha\}).
$$

I am trying to figure out a way to control the error sensitivity of this problem. If the function values are close to $\alpha$, then a small perturbation of the function could dramatically change the measure. Any suggestions as to what tools I could use would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: More precisely, you want to control the difference $$|\Lambda(f)-\Lambda(g)|, $$ right?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: You could try to use Chebyshev's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_statement

Answer (score 1):

The following standard trick might be useful. Let 
$$
\Lambda_\alpha(f):=|\{f>\alpha\}|.$$ 
Consider another function $g\in L^1$. If $f(x)+g(x)>\alpha$, then either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ or both must be bigger than $\alpha/2$; 
$$
\{f+g>\alpha\}\subset \{f>\tfrac\alpha2\}\cup\{g>\tfrac\alpha2\}.$$ 
Therefore 
$$\tag{1}
\Lambda_\alpha(f+g)\le \Lambda_{\alpha/2}(f)+\Lambda_{\alpha/2}(g).$$ 
Now, adding and subtracting $g$, we see that 
$$
\Lambda_{2\alpha}(f)\le \Lambda_{\alpha}(f-g) +\Lambda_\alpha(g), $$ 
which gives the bound 
$$
\tag{2} 
\Lambda_{2\alpha}(f)-\Lambda_\alpha (g)\le \Lambda_{\alpha}(f-g).$$

This is not very pretty, but maybe it helps. If $\alpha>0$, then you can combine it with Chebyshev's inequality, yielding 
$$
\max(\Lambda_{2\alpha}(f)-\Lambda_\alpha(g), \Lambda_{2\alpha}(g)-\Lambda_\alpha(f))\le \frac{1}{\alpha}\|f-g\|_1.$$

Comment: Thank you my friend!